# Magnific popup on button click

Tags: jquery, html, magnific-popup

for the life of me I can't get this to work. I just want to click a video button to pull up my video gallery.

HTML

```
{{-- Button for video gallery --}}

<div class="margin-top">
    <button class="button--video button video-gallery" data-mfp-src="video-gallery">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Videos
    </button>
</div>

{{-- Video gallery, hidden because the user doesn't need to see this --}}
<section>
    <div class="video-gallery">

        <a class="magnific-youtube item" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vrdgDdPApQ" data-title="item 1">Video #2</a>

        <a class="magnific-youtube item" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RUGmBxe65U" data-title="item 1">Video #3</a>

        <a class="magnific-youtube item" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U" data-title="item 1">Video #4</a>

    </div>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
$( ".button--video" ).click(function() {
    $('.video-gallery').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'iframe',
            tLoading: 'Loading video #%curr%...',
            mainClass: 'mfp-iframe',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            },
            iframe: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">This video #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function (item) {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: You said it's hidden so... have you tried unhiding it?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the event, you can set id to container:

```
<div id="container--video" class="margin-top">
    <button class="button--video button video-gallery" data-mfp-src="video-gallery">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Videos
    </button>
</div>
```

And the event:

```
$( "#container--video" ).click(".button--video", function() {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, your idea pointed me in the right direction I needed to go in order to fix my problem. I've posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well my first mistake was targeting the video gallery container, that isn't going to launch Magnific popup, I needed to target a link that Magnific Popup could read and open inside the video container. My second mistake was not realising that I needed to basically simulate two clicks.

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="video-gallery is-hidden">

        <a class="first-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vrdgDdPApQ" data-title="item 1">Video #2</a>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RUGmBxe65U" data-title="item 1">Video #3</a>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U" data-title="item 1">Video #4</a>

    </div>
</section>
```

Java script

```
$('.button--video').click(function(){ //When user clicks the button
    $(".first-video").click();//simulate click on first video link
});

$('.video-gallery').magnificPopup({ //magnific makes a gallery from any links in this container.
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'iframe',
        tLoading: 'Loading video #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-iframe',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        },
        iframe: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">This video #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
            titleSrc: function (item) {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
);
```

By simulating a click to a class called "first-video", Magnific popup can then open my hidden video gallery, allowing the user to navigate through the video list through Magnific popup. By having a class only on the first video link, I know the user is always going to the open that video link first.